# How to get a column of fuzzy scores (comparing one string to an column of strings) in a dataframe, python

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe that lists objects and their different qualities in columns. One of those columns is the objects' colors. My goal is to write a function that creates a NEW column listing the fuzzy partial_ratio scores between the color of a SINGLE object (i.e., `'orange'`) to all the other objects' colors (i.e., `"navy blue"`, `"white"`, `"red-orange"`).

Firstly, I have a function that searches the dataframe to find the color of the object. Its title is `findcolor(object)`. If I call `findcolor(pumpkin)` it searches the row `'pumpkin'` and column `'Color'` and returns the string `"orange"` (which is in that cell). I am calling this function inside *another* function, below, which allows me to compare two objects' colors inside the dataframe.

```
def getsingleFuzzyScore(object1,object2):
    x = findcolor(object2)
    b = findcolor(object1)
    if b in x:  
       return 100
    elif x in b:
       return 100
    else:
       return(fuzz.partial_ratio(b,x))
```

So, essentially if any of `object1`'s color is contained in `object2`'s color and vice versa, my score will be 100, otherwise, it will take the partial fuzzy ratio of the two colors in comparison. This information-- that is, my rendition of FuzzyScore-- I want as a new column in the dataframe.

Where I am struggling is inputting the `'Color'` column from the dataframe. This question ([Comparing a single string to an array of strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806788/comparing-a-single-string-to-an-array-of-strings-in-c)) is what I am looking to do (but in python), and I would like to be able to call the object's column, i.e., `'Color'` and have the color of pumpkin be compared to EACH of the remaining objects in the `'Color'` column.

In conclusion, I would like to see the output be a column of numbers that are the outputs of `getsingleFuzzScore` for EACH object compared to the color of the object I input.

Comment: Please provide an example and what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: def listfuzzscoreColor(object):
     a = findcolor(object)
     colorarray = df['Color']
     strcolorarray = str(colorarray)
     return strcolorarray
     for x in strcolorarray:
         if a in x:  
             return 100
         elif x in a:
             return 100         else:
           return 11#(fuzz.partial_ratio(b,x))

And then I put this in to create a column in the df. #df['FuzzScores'].apply(listfuzzscoreColor(pumpkin))